# Type signature as function

Tags: haskell

I have following type constructor and data constructor:

```
data Compose f g x = MkCompose (f (g x))
```

Get type signature in the prelude about Compose, it shows:

```
MkCompose :: f (g x) -> Compose f g x
```

Why it shows like a function?

When I apply the type as following:

```
*ComposeExercise> :t MkCompose [[42]]
MkCompose [[42]] :: Num x => Compose [] [] x
```

Then for me, it is clear.

Comment: Because that is the most generic signature. Mind that `MkCompose` is a constructor. In your second example, the parameter is already filled in.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? `MkCompose` is a constructor, it's a function by definition. What exactly isn't clear about that?

Comment: Aha. I am so stupid. It was not clear why it shows as function `f (g x) -> Compose f g x`.

Comment: What type were you expecting `MkCompose` to have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write:

```
data Compose f g x = MkCompose (f (g x))
```

You are saying that:

```
MkCompose :: f (g x) -> Compose f g x
```

That is the definition of `Compose`; this is what a `data` declaration does.

However, when you give it an argument (since it is a function), like the following, `f`, `g`, and `x` are given specific types:

```
λ> :t MkCompose [[1]]                    -- f = [], g = [], x = Num n => n.
MkCompose 1 :: Num n => Compose [] [] n  -- As in the definition.
```

`MkCompose` has a function type exactly because it is a function; it takes a value and returns another.

If this isn't clear, here are some other examples:

- `MkCompose (Just [1]) :: Num n => Compose Maybe [] n`, since `Just [1] :: Num n => Maybe [n]`. In this case, `f = Maybe`, `g = []`, and `x = Num n => n`.
- `MkCompose getLine :: Compose IO [] Char`, since `getLine :: IO [Char]`. In this case, `f = IO`, `g = []`, and `x = Char`.
- `MkCompose [[]] :: Compose [] [] x`, since `[[]] :: [[x]]`. In this case, `f = []`, `g = []`, but `x` can be anything.